# RewriteRule redirect to another url with variable

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I need to redirect: 
http://domain.com/myfile.php?key=variable

to

http://domain.com/mypage/?key=variable

I got empty key value:
`RewriteRule ^myfile.php$ /mypage/?key=$1 [R=301,L]`

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this what you are looking for. This should get you going. Let me know.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myfile.php$ /mypage/?key=%1 [L,R=301]
```